# how to query google checkout ending balance?

Tags: api, android-widget, google-checkout, android-pay

Writing an android widget to display the most current Google checkout ending balance and can not figure out how to get this number directly. I have dissected the page but don't understand how the number is generated. I can gain access through a simple browser interface and view my daily ending balance but cant pull that single number for display on the widget. Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently aren't any Authorization APIs to request balance.

In order to get this information, you would need to request the Google login credentials from the user which is something that Google probably doesn't want you to do(the reason why client login was deprecated).

I can't think of a great solution to this problem with out Google enabling an OAuth2 API.